# Удаление файлов по расширению. Удаляемые файлы вывести

Tags: linux, файлы, bash

Удаление файлов по расширению. Удаляемые файлы вывести.

Первая часть задания работает, а вот как добавить вывод к этому?

```
find $1 -name "*.$2" -print0 | xargs -0r rm --
```

Answer (score 1):

Самым простым способом будет добавление ключа `-t` утилите **xargs**. В этом случае она напечатает выполняемую команду.

Однако если такой формат вывода не устраивает, можно скопировать вывода утилиты **find** во временный файл. А затем напечатать его содержимое. Например,

```
tempfile=`mktemp`
find "$1" -name "*.$2" -print0 | tee "${tempfile}" | xargs -0r rm --
cat "${tempfile}" | xargs -0ri echo "Файл '{}' был удалён"
rm -- "${tempfile}"
```

Comment: Или даже немного сжульничать: вначале печатать сообщения, а потом уж удалять

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

если просто вывести в строку удаленные файлы то можно попробовать так:

```
find $1 -name "*.$2" -print0 -delete
```

или

```
find $1 -name "*.$2" -print0 -exec rm {} +
```

Вывод будет примерно таким:

```
./1.txt./2.txt./3.txt
```